# Calling a C binary with python discord bot on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord, discord.py

I have a question, I coded just a basic python bot, one of the commands called "ascii" takes an input from the ctx and then with subproccess.py calls a C binary, that pretty much just writes the input with "#" and " ", everything works fine when I run it on my pc, but I just put the bot on heroku and this doesn't work (other commands work), I call it with

`subprocess.check_output("ascii \"" + " ".join(text) + "\"", shell=True)`

In logs I get 
`Command 'ascii "input"' returned non-zero exit status 127.`
which from what I've found meand that command was not found, so I guess I will have to add a directiory to the path (like /apps/bot/ascii or something) but I can't figure out what exactly to put in there or if this even is the issue.

Any ideas how to make it work?

edit_1: I tried to change the calling of the function to `/app/ascii` which should be the directory I thought at least, but now it returns exit status 126, which is that the command is not a executable

edit_2: Just tried to run ascii with console on heroku, at first permission denied, but after I gave it permission, it worked. Do I need to somehow set global permission to ascii? Like in requirements.txt or something?

Comment: The command you're trying to run is `ascii`? What does that do? Where did you get it from? (It might be possible to use it; knowing what it is and where it comes from will help answer for sure.)

Comment: it is a little program that I wrote as a school homework, pretty much what it does is it takes the input that I call it with and prints it out in bigger, only using # and spaces, it prints it to stdout so that's why I have the subproccess to check_output, I don't think there is a problem in that, cause I ran the bot on my computer with a batch file and everything worked fine, just the calling on heroku is probably different

Comment: Is `ascii` committed to your Git repository? If so, where did you compile it?

Comment: The code was compiled on my computer, then the .out binary was committed to github. (the same binary that worked on my pc)

Comment: What operating system is on your local computer? Generally speaking, C code compiled on one type of machine (operating system and CPU architecture) won't work on another. Also, you say "the .out binary" but your command is `ascii`. Should it be `ascii.out` / do you need to rename the file to just `ascii`?

Comment: I'm running windows 10, tho I compiled it on Ubuntu WSL with gcc, as to the naming, I've found that subproccess launches the program in shell, meaning the .out extension is not required, more so, if you add it, it doesn't work even locally. So what you're saying is that I need to compile the program on Heroku?

Comment: Ideally, yes, it would be built on Heroku during your build process. (You can't do it after the build, e.g. via `heroku run bash`, because of Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). The binary will be lost on the next dyno restart.) You might be able to use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) and something like [the C buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/atris/heroku-buildpack-c) alongside Python.

Comment: Tried it, after few fixes and getting to understand how the stuff works and a lot of trial and error, I got it to work exactly how I wanted. Thank you very much <3

Comment: Also, could you just write something as an answer so I can accept it? I don't see an option to accept your comment as an answer :)

Comment: I'm glad you got this working, but I'm not exactly sure how you did. I gave you some hints but not enough for an answer (otherwise I would have written one). Feel free to [add your own](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), though! Self-answering is encouraged on Stack Overflow. Good job pushing through this to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo,
for anyone that would like to do this kind of thing, I would say, don't..
I've had a lot of trouble with the setup of this, but now, it actually works well it seems, no problems so far, but looking back, it would be much faster if I just re-wrote the .c file into python, not that difficult, much faster in the end.
That said, I will tell you how I got it working and by following it, you may get it working fairly fast.

To the "tutorial":
Firstly, calling the binary as I have it in the post worked perfectly, no changes needed for that.

On the github from which it was deployed I needed to add as per usual with heroku apps a procfile (you can search on the internet, pretty much 1 line of code calling the worker, the .py bot file), requirements.txt (where the non-standart libraries that I used had to be added, discord and asyncio for me) and runtime.txt (forced it to run python 3.6.8, actually probably not needed). Also, a [makefile](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/) that I had to create. Don't forget to upload all needed .c and .h files you want to be using. That should be it on github.

Now to heroku:

firstly create a new app, I have not yet connected it to the github. Then I have added a 
[C buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/atris/heroku-buildpack-c)(that is what the makefile is for), and added the python buildpack that is on heroku. Then I went back to deploy and connected the github, enabled automated deploys for good measure and deployed. Now just go back to overview, configure dynos and you 'should' only see one worker, the one you added in the Procfile. Activate it and if I haven't forgotten any steps then the .c file should compile with make and the makefile and should be able to run when called by python.

Now that I look at it, it looks like 20 minutes of work lol, I spent like 2,5 days on trying to get it work...

Well, at least now you don't have to go through what I did, if anyone ever needs to do this :)

If you have any more questions, I will try to help, shoot a message, here or discord (my name is exactly the same as here and will remain so)